# C# selenium Not able to locate table(highlighted in the table) to to perform click action. PFA screenshot of elements page below here with code sippet

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Screenshot of elements present in web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N96z4.jpg)

```
_driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
IWebElement item = FindElement(By.Id("__gadget_4"));
_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(item);
elements = FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));
foreach (var frame in elements)
{
    _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
    item = FindElement(By.Id("treeview-1027-record-8"));
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: Try with this xpath for table and check
item  =  FindElement(By.xpath(//div[@class=='x-grid-item-container']//table[@id='treeview-1027-record-8']));

Comment: It's not working out. It's issue with the frame. Because I'm not able to switch to the inner most frame in which control resides.

Comment: First arrange the code and provide proper issue, it helps other to see your issue

Comment: @iamsankalp89 please find the element in screenshot attached with the link at the top

Answer (score 0):

Directly switch to child frame and then perform action on element you want. Just try this code & check

```
WebElement wb = _driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div/iframe[@id"__gadget_2"]"))    
_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(wb);
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("treeview-1027-record-8")).Click();
```

Comment: I'm not able to find that inner most frame "__gadget_2".. While searching for that frame with Id and xpath, it's getting timed out everytime. I think due to that only I'm not able to find this table also becuase it resides under this frame only.

Comment: Edited answer, check it now.

Comment: Also what exactly you want to in table, it seems you are just clicking on table. Is table clickable? It might be possible code for switching is correct, problem might be happening with action on table

Comment: Nope actually I'm debugging it and while debugging i found it's not able to find iframe "__gadget_2" so only not able to switch. And yes table is clickable, they have used Java script in code behind for to make static control as dynamic.

Comment: I have edited my reply. Since that particular frame is just child of a div, so wrote xpath based on that. Also I would suggest you copy the id __gadget_2 from source instead of writing it on your self

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using loop just goto frame and click element

```
_driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
IWebElement FrameName= FindElement(By.Id("__gadget_4"));
_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(FrameName);
    item = FindElement(By.Id("treeview-1027-record-8"));
item.Click();
```

Also as @Shoaib Akhtar says you can directly use name to switch to frame, Also you can use xpaths

```
IWebElement FrameName= FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe[@name='__gadget_4']"));
    _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(FrameName);
```

OR

```
IWebElement FrameName= FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe[@id='__gadget_4']"));
    _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(FrameName);
```

Comment: It is switching to the frame "__gadget_4" but could not find the element and got timed out.Even I tried to switch to the frame directly but not able to find the table (treeview-1027-record-8) with  and with Xpath also. One more thing I'm not able to find that inner most frame "__gadget_2".. While searching for that frame with Id and xpath, it's getting timed out everytime. I think due to that only I'm not able to find this table also becuase it resides under this frame only.